# How can I use Excel for project management?

Tags: excel, project-management, scheduling

Joel often talks about using MS Excel for lightweight project management, but I'm curious about actual implementations of this idea. I've seen some templates that seem to clone MS Project via macros, which would be overkill for a lightweight project. Anyone have any useful templates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
    feature    task       estimated hours actual hours current %
    ---------- ---------- --------------- ------------ ---------
```

if estimated hours times current % is greater than actual hours, you are behind schedule

update the actual hours and current % on a daily basis

see also [joel's old excel template](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000245.html)

Comment: Haha I love the fog creek pitch at the top of the article

Comment: In addition to the setup shown by Steven, you could add filters to sort through task owners and such.  We use that at work and it's very useful.

Comment: in practice i use a template slightly more complex, but this is the gist of it - just enough to let you know that you screwed up an estimate and/or are in danger of blowing a deadline

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit off-topic, but you might want to consider testing **[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com)**. There is a Gantt chart widget provided by **Viewpath** in the *"Insert->Widget..."* menu option.

Answer (score 2):

You have some pretty advance template with [Pipetalk Scheduler](http://pipetalk.stores.yahoo.net/frdopiexgasc.html)

[alt text http://ep.yimg.com/ip/I/pipetalk_2055_216386](http://ep.yimg.com/ip/I/pipetalk_2055_216386)

However, since it seems to be a *little too much*, I just transfered that to the **[worst UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177#289284)** ;)

Comment: holy cow..i need something a *bit* more lightweight

Comment: ya gotta be kidding - ms-project is less complicated

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote. But it does deserve a WTF. No, several WTFs. Let me start: WTF.

Comment: By all means, downvote away ;-) Mister "Community wiki" will loose some rep' though...

Comment: I agree with Thomas. No downvote, but: Whiskey Tango Foxtrot??? They're actually hoping to make money with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not excel, but I saw [scrumy](https://scrumy.com/) and liked it's [demo](https://scrumy.com/demo). For a small project recently, I just generated a project plan using 'Cross Functional Flowchart' under Business Process with some flow/process stuff in Visio.

Comment: Cool app, just unfortunate I can't host it myself (not really comfortable with exposing company confidential information on a publicly facing website).

Comment: What category is the activity chart under in Visio? And what version of Visio are you running?

Comment: @Luke, sorry about the links. I'm also must be crazy since the Visio template is called 'Cross Functional Flowchart' under Business Processs Visio Pro'03.

Comment: I use shape color on the 'CFP' to designate status (new, modified/in-progress, done, etc....)

Comment: BTW: on scrumy, you can pay small-$ for a secure site.

Answer (score 1):

Edward Tufte - aka "the man" when it comes to data representation has done a lot of work on Gantt charts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) has some good information on this topic, but basically it boils down to using Excel as a Gantt chart creator, the advantage being that it's simple and won't get in your way much:

http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=000076

Comment: Thanks for the link Kurt, i'm a big fan of Tuft and have a love/hate Gantts. They are great for scheduling but are only readable to the scheduler. To have "the man" chime in on Gantts is great.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [Sprint Backlog](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/scrum/simple-sprint-backlog). You estimate the time for every tasks of your project and your update the estimated **remaining** time every day or so. Then you have a burndown chart that shows the remaining effort to complete the project.

If your project is too large for a daily tracking, you could either do the tracking every week, or manage a [product backlog](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/scrum/simple-product-backlog) of the things to be done in your project as a coarse-grained level of planning and then choose the most prioritized one for the finer-grained planning level.

You might want to look at Scrum(1) or any other [agile methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) for lightweight development methods for further details.

(1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)

Answer (score 1):

If you like using spreadsheets and not getting involved with too many fancy tools, have a look at [The One Page Project Manager](http://www.onepageprojectmanager.com/) - it's exactly as described, a nice, lightweight way to keep track of all your important project info on a single worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Much **simpler**: some [**Gantt graph** in Excel](http://www.hyperthot.com/pm_excel_gantt.htm) ,as **[illustrated here](http://fr.youtube.com/watch?v=CW_wGSFavTc)**.

Answer (score 0):

The columns I use are

1) Task Name
2) Budget Hours 
3) Total Hours
4) Remaining Hours

The Key is column (4).  Rather than getting the person to estimate a percent complete; get them to re-estimate from this point forward.  Its a subtle change but the mindset is much different.  Otherwise you almost always end up stuck at 90% complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of useful template in [this](http://www.exinfm.com/free_spreadsheets.html) page. Also, you can read more in our [project management software](http://xprojectmanagement.com) blog.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

I use   EasyProjectPlan  which is an **Excel Project Plan** that syncs with **Outlook** and **MSProject**.

**[www.EasyProjectPlan.com](http://www.easyprojectplan.com)**

I use the Outlook and Calendar sync features to distribute and collect task information to my team members.

I distribute the EPP Excel file to all team members either by email or I post it in a shared folder.

My team members can edit the EPP excel file and send the changes back to me.

Most of the companies I work for have no PM task management system so EPP allows me to walk onto any project and immediately distribute and collect task information to all team members. Considering that most companies use Excel and Outlook, there is nothing to install on any computer.

In my experience, team members prefer to view task information in Excel and Outlook.